# how to avoid $push-ing nulls in mongo aggregation framework

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

$push is aggregating nulls if the field is not present.
I would like to avoid this.

Is there a way to make a sub expression for $push operator in such way that null values will be skipped and not pushed into the resulting array ?

Answer (score 28):

Bit late to the party, but..

I wanted to do the same thing, and found that I could accomplish it with an expression like this:

```
  // Pushes events only if they have the value 'A'
  "events": {
    "$push": {
      "$cond": [
        {
          "$eq": [
            "$event",
            "A"
          ]
        },
        "A",
        "$noval"
      ]
    }
  }
```

The thinking here is that when you do

```
{ "$push": "$event" }
```

then it seems to only push non-null values.

So I made up a column that doesn't exist, $noval, to be returned as the false condition of my $cond.

It seems to work. I'm not sure if it is non-standard and therefore susceptible to breaking one day but..

Comment: This works, but it cannot be used with indexes and will always use `collscan` to see if the non-existing value exists.

Comment: Worked in my case, thank you. You saved me a lot of time.

Comment: thanks you `$noval` worked for me :lol: they should have add `$$REMOVE` in this situation.

Answer (score 10):

It's really not completely clear what your specific case is without an example. There is the [**`$ifNull`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) operator which can "replace" a null value or missing field with "something else", but to truly "skip" is not possible.

That said, you can always "filter" the results depending on your actual use case.

If your resulting data is actually a "Set" and you have a MongoDB version that is 2.6 or greater then you can use [**`$setDifference`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/) with some help from [**`$addToSet`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/) to reduce the number of `null` values that are kept initially:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$key",
        "list": { "$addToSet": "$field" }
    }},
    { "$project": {
        "list": { "$setDifference": [ "$list", [null] ] }
    }}
])
```

So there would only be one `null` and then the `$setDifference` operation will "filter" that out in the comparison.

In earlier versions or when the values are not in fact "unique" and not a "set", then you "filter" by processing with [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) and [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/):

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$key",
        "list": { "$push": "$field" }
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$list" },
    { "$match": { "list": { "$ne": null } }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "list": { "$push": "$list" }
    }}
])
```

If you don't want to be "destructive" of arrays that would end up "empty" because they contained "nothing but" `null`, then you keep a count use `$ifNull` and match on the conditions:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$key",
        "list": { "$push": "$field" },
        "count": { 
            "$sum": { 
                "$cond": [
                    { "$eq": { "$ifNull": [ "$field", null ] }, null },
                    0,
                    1
                ]
            }
        }
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$list" },
    { "$match": {
        "$or": [
            { "list": { "$ne": null } },
            { "count": 0 }
        ]
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "list": { "$push": "$list" }
    }},
    { "$project": {
        "list": {
            "$cond": [
                { "$eq": [ "$count", 0 ] },
                { "$const": [] },
                "$list"
            ]
        }
    }}
])
```

With a final [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) replacing any array that simply consisted of `null` values only with an empty array object.